# Utilize the active voice in sentences when an actor is undefined

Tags: passive-voice, technical, active-voice

I am writing the technical documentation that describes some actions to be done.

For example:

> The new sewer water line may be connected to the old one in room A546 or to the new one in room A549.

I know the English language prefers active voice to passive, but how should I address all the actions if the actor is undefined?

Comment: The English language uses the passive where it's the sensible choice (or rather sensible people do). As here. // A problem that does arise here, however, is ambiguity. 'The new sewer water line may be connected, when the time comes, ...' vs 'It may be that the new sewer water line has been connected ...'. Dynamic vs stative. Possibly, prior context will clarify.

Comment: What you say does not apply to technical writing like this. The passive is perfectly accurate here. Pipes are said to be connected to other pipes. And there is no reason to say by plumbers, is there? May I suggest you google up some tech manuals and read them prior to embarking on your joined-up writing? :)

Comment: [by the way, for passive voice, we say agent, not actor. :)]

Comment: Please stop knowing that "the English language prefers active voice to passive" immediately. You are not allowed to know things that are false, like "the earth is flat" or "English sentences should use active and not passive". You can only believe them, despite all evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mention in comments, the passive voice is not incorrect and, in fact, is entirely appropriate when the agent is unknown. If you insist on using the active voice (though I see no reason for such insistence), you could try [the impersonal "you"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you):

> You may connect the new sewer water line to the old one in room A546 or to the new one in room A549.

The pronoun "one" is also grammatically possible but would probably sound awkward in the context of a set of instructions:

> One may connect the new sewer water line to the old one in room A546 or to the new one in room A549.